# Revert popup form values in MODX manager

Tags: javascript, php, modx, modx-revolution

I have a plugin that was developed for a MODX site.  This plugin basically handles form submissions and displays them, along with some extra data.  On the manager side, there's an interface (looks like [MODx.grid.Grid](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/custom-manager-pages/modext/modx.grid.grid)) showing these form submissions.  If I right click one of the table rows, I see "Detail View", "View Notes", and "Change Status".  If I click on "Change Status", I get a popup box (looks like [MODx.Window](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/custom-manager-pages/modext/modx.window)) that lets me change some of the form values like who it has been assigned to, etc.  When I click "Save", the value is saved and the popup box goes away.  If I then right click on another row and do "Change Status", I get the same popup box with the previous row's values in it.

Normally I would think a question like this would be too specific for SO, but the popup box seems to be handled BY MODX and not this custom plugin.

Is there a way in MODX to attach to the save event of this popup form and clear out some values?

If this is way too specific, just let me know and I'll try elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to pass `blankValues: true` where the MODx.Window was being called.